# Ubuntu 22.04 won't boot up anymore

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 on a dual boot along Windows 11 on my ThinkBook. I have been doing so for over a year now with no problems. Today As I wanted to boot back into Ubuntu I get the message:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p5: recovering journal
/dev/nvme0n1p5: clean, 414286/10256384 files, 39275000/41010688 blocks
[    3.177929] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page found
[    3.177961] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[    3.481636] mt7921e 0000:04:00.0: ASIC revision: 79610010
[    3.606066] mt7921e 0000:04:00.0: Firmware init done
```

I made a new installation usb stick, but it won't give me the option to repair. Any ideas?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did Windows do an update and reset Windows settings or also do an UEFI udpate changing UEFI settings to defaults. That may turn UEFI Secure boot back on, or change other settings you originally changed to boot Ubuntu. Check UEFI settings.

Comment: Hi, yes there was an update. But it seems that my Ubuntu partition was so full that it could not be loaded? No idea how it got full, but anyhoo... I was not able to delete or move anything, sooooo....I decided to bite the bullet and just reinstall Ubuntu...everything is back to normal. Thank you for your help and time! Cheers!

Comment: You need to make sure you have a large enough / (root) partition. And/or make sure you do not have some issue that fills log files. I include in my update & cleanup script this command, at start & end of script so I can see use in every partition. `df -hT -x squashfs -x tmpfs -x devtmpfs`

Comment: Thank you very much. I was loosing disk space for some reason, so I just erased the partition and reinstalled Ubuntu again...